# Calling jar in my java code

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use a jar file Command.jar in my java code. When I run Command.jar from command line
like this java -jar Command.jar "Param1" it works well. But when I try to run it in my java code using either Process builder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec it does not work.

I tried this -

```
List <String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("java -jar");
command.add("Command.jar");
command.add("Param1");

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
try {
    Process process = builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

It does not work. I also tried this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Command.jar Param1");
```

But no luck. Please tell me where I am doing wrong

Comment: What in particular is not working? Is there an error?

Comment: You should obtain the process output, and log it. I think the most probable cause it's because "java" command is not visible

Comment: I think I have to give absolute path of Command.jar so it should be like this  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "C:\\Users\\sj\\Desktop\\Command.jar");

Comment: can you please tell how to pass this line into processbuilder        java -Drootdir="Argument1" -jar Command.jar "Argument2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
command.add("java -jar");
```

It should be

```
command.add("java");
command.add("-jar");
```

But there may be other problems as well.  For instance `java` may not be accessible via the search path given by the PATH environment variable.  Or `Command.jar` may not be in the current directory.

You need to see what (if anything) is being written by the `java` command to its standard output and/or standard error streams.

Comment: can you please tell how to pass this line into processbuilder        java -Drootdir="Argument1" -jar Command.jar "Argument2"

Comment: Do you want the quote characters to be part of the argument string or not?

Comment: In that case, the command / argument `String[]` should be this: `new String[]{"java", "-Drootdir=Argument1", "-jar", "Command.jar", "Argument2"}`.  It would be best to use *absolute* pathnames for the `java` command and the `Command.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

> it does not work

does not tell us how to help you. You'll need to give us an error message or undesired result. Use `System.out.println`'s to help you debug and narrow the problem.

From what I can guess from personal experience and other problems is that you probably ran some `cd "Directory\With\Path\To\Jar"` commands in command prompt when you were running it manually. You'll need to do the same for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` or put the jar in the location that `exec` will default to in your program.

Comment: You may also want to add a note about `e.printStackTrace();` since his code is silently ignoring an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using ProcessBuilder(java.lang.ProcessBuilder)? Syntax is as follows -

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "absolute path upto jar");
Process p = pb.start();
```

You can redirent input/output/error to/from files as follows

```
File commands = new File("absolute path to inputs file");
File dirOut = new File("absolute path to outputs file");
File dirErr = new File("absolute path to error file");

dirProcess.redirectInput(commands);
dirProcess.redirectOutput(dirOut);
dirProcess.redirectError(dirErr);
```

I have tried it and it work! Let us know any errors or exceptions you are getting.

Comment: I don't think this works in java 1.6 there is no redirectInput method in 1.6 is there any other solution which can be run on 1.6 and one more thing if i want to pass arguments with my jar then where should I pass them . As I can not pass in  new     ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "absolute path upto jar");

Comment: i got the ans I used outstream and inputstream and it is working . thanks

Comment: can you please tell how to pass this line into processbuilder        java -Drootdir="Argument1" -jar Command.jar "Argument2"